# How to format NSDate?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

How can I get my NSDate to display in the format for example i.e "Tue Feb 26, 2011"

Comment: There are already many questions here about [NSDate formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nsdate+format), does none of them work for you?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Do it right. **Don't hardcode your date formats.** There are countries that are not your country and they might have different date formats. So if you want to show this date to the user you should use a method that takes the users locale into account.

You could use the `dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:` method introduced in iOS4 to get the appropriate format with all the information you want.
And if you have to support iOS < 4 you should create a plist with this template method to create the correct date format for the user locale.

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease]; 
NSString *dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"E MMM d yyyy" options:0 locale:locale];
[formatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
NSLog(@"Formatted date: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:myDate]);
```

gives `So., 27. Feb 2011` for my locale.
and `Sun, Feb 27, 2011` for the en_US locale

Comment: Sounds like someone is upset about always seeing US formatted dates ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateFormatter *gmtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
[gmtFormatter setDateFormat:@"E MMM d yyyy"];
```