# NSDate returning different value on conversion from string - Not GMT related

Tags: ios, nsdate

I hope this isn't GMT related or I will feel rather stupid.

2 quick related questions. Why is this converting to a different date? Is losing a day. I looked at time zones as stated in other answers but it is always the GMT timezone **0000** which is what I expected. I presume the error is  in my **setDateFormat** but I can't see how to fix it.

```
NSString *stringFromDate = self.dateLabel.currentTitle;
NSLog(@"StringFromDateWeight! %@", stringFromDate);

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//Convert Back to NSDate
[df setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];

NSDate *inputedDate = [df dateFromString: stringFromDate];
NSLog(@"StringFromDateWeight2! %@", inputedDate);
```

`NSLog(@"StringFromDateWeight! %@", stringFromDate);` is
**17072013**

```
NSLog(@"StringFromDateWeight2! %@", inputedDate); is
```

**2013-07-16 23:00:00 +0000**

I am also using the code below to compare 2 dates and am I right in that it returns in seconds? How would I change it to return in days?

```
int intervall = (int) [theDate timeIntervalSinceDate: now];
```

Comment: It is indeed a timezone issue. When you convert the string to NSDate the dateFormatter uses your local timezone. Which appears to be UTC+1 and "midnight July 17" in your local timezone is "July 16 23:00:00" in UTC. If you want to calculate in UTC you have to set the timezone of the dateFormatter `df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];` If you don't want to do this don't trust NSLog'd NSDates, use `[inputedDate descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]`. It's usually better to not look at the UTC date at all. It confuses stackoverflow users every day. ;-)

Comment: @MatthiasBauch thank you very much that fixed it. I upvoted u as it is very close to a answer tbh. Any thoughts on the final bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't explicitly set a timezone `NSDateFormatter` will use your local timezone. You don't set one, so your formatter will create a NSDate that is at "midnight July 17" in your timezone. The `description` method of NSDate will return a date that is formatted in UTC timezone. Since you get "July 16 23:00:00" I guess your timezone is UTC+1.

You have two options. Calculate in UTC by setting the timezone explicitly.

```
df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

Or, usually more useful, don't look at the `description` of NSDate and use `[inputedDate descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]` for debugging, which will print the date formatted for your timezone.
If you want to display the date to the user use another `NSDateFormatter` (preferably with dateStyle and timeStyle and not dateFormat, because [hardcoded dateFormats are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5132177/457406))

It's just the display that is different, the underlying NSDate object is still the same.

---

Regarding your second question:

In many timezones there are 2 days each year that don't have 24 hours, so you can't calculate anything with the seconds you get from `timeIntervalSinceDate:`.

You have to use [`NSDateComponents`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/) and [`NSCalendar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html). Fortunately there is already a method that does exactly what you want. [`components:fromDate:toDate:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/components:fromDate:toDate:options:)

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:inputedDate toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
NSLog(@"Date was %d days (and %d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds) ago", components.day, components.hour, components.minute, components.second);
```

If you only need the number of days you can remove all components except `NSDayCalendarUnit`