# Can I use date format mm/dd/yy?

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

Is it possible to perform date calculations with a 2-digit year, such as, mm/dd/yy? Or is that not advisable for some reason?

For example, all my date formats say `[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy"];`. Can I change this to `[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yy"];` or would there be any unforeseen consequences when performing date calculations?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, my date format should say MM/dd/yy, not mm/dd/yy, as small m equals minutes. Still, can I use 2-digit years? I am unable to find the answer anywhere...

Comment: date calculations are done with NSDate and tis is independent of the format used

Comment: Yes, you can use a 2-digit year.  You can even use a 1-digit year.  See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 2):

I think you should always respect the current culture settings of the end user. But perhaps you have a special program where you are parsing or generating external files that must use a specific format, for example a log file or a DBase file, yes then giving a specific format is useful.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I'm sure my end user is fine with 01/01/12 rather than 01/01/2012.

Comment: Over here in Europe, we write dd/MM/yy,so using a fixed mm/dd/yy is frighteningly confusing (it's the stuff that makes rocket crash). So if you need a localised short format, use `NSDateFormatterShortStyle`

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: No. Over here (like literally) in Europe we write dd.MM.yy ;-) [Don't hardcode your dateFormats if you want to show them to the user.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131913/how-to-format-nsdate/5132177#5132177)

Comment: Exactly my point. Italy uses '.', netherlands uses '/’, others use '-’. Many different separators. Not much of a problem, but the order of month numbers and day numbers is mostly consistent in europe. Only America has them the other way around, (which is strange, as they were mostly populated by europeans)

Comment: Makes sense. I actually grew up with dd/MM/yy... however, my app will only available in the USA and only useful in CA. I appreciate all the comments!

Comment: This is why I prefer dd MMM yyyy -- about as unambiguous as one can hope for, in human-to-human communication.  (But it does confuse folks from Alpha Centauri Beta.)

Comment: Thats part of why ISO came up with the canonical format. It always goes from big to small (except timezone) and is sortable as text.

Answer (score 2):

Date calculations should be done with [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instances which are independent of the date format. The format is only used when converting to and from a string for input and output. The formatting is done as per the [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes You Can use it. try following code.

NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateformate setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YY"];

NSString *date_String=[dateformate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"Today: %@", date_String);