# NSDateFormatter for day and month name

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get date in the format Monday, March 09, 2015. But following code is not returning required date format. I think I am using wrong Formatter. Here is the code:

```
NSString *dateString = @"09-03-2015";
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"];
        NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
        NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: change this line  `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"];` to  `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];`

Comment: There is no point creating a date and then replacing it with the result of the formatter. Also, log the result, not a string you then try to create from the result.

Comment: For the sake of your users, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5132177/457406

Comment: @SumitGarg but this doesn't return the required format like Monday, March 09, 2015

Comment: ok now used this date format `EEE, MMM dd, yyyy`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this...

```
//Getting date from string
    NSString *dateString = @"09-03-2015";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
// converting into our required date format    
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"];
    NSString *reqDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"date is %@", reqDateString);

LOG:2015-03-09 12:40:33.456 TestCode [1377:38775] date is Monday, March 09, 2015
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. Just a little thing. it's giving year like 0015. But I need it like 2015. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Ah okay. Got it. I was passing 09-03-15

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must convert your `dateString` to `NSDate`value

```
NSString *dateString = @"09-03-2015";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

after that you could use this format: `@"EEEE,MMMM dd, yyyy"` to convert that `dateValue` to dateString like `Monday, March 09, 2015` 
Hope this help
[Helpful](https://tahabebek.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/format-string-for-the-iphone-nsdateformatter/) link for you

Answer (score 0):

Try to set dateFormat property to `@"dd'-'MM'-'yyyy"` . Always check the unicode the [date symbol table](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns). "MMMM" means that the date month should be a full month name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
    NSString * yourJSONString = @"09-03-2015";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];;
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourJSONString];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE,LLLL dd, yyyy"];
    NSString *output = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
    NSLog(@"%@", output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString * format = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EEEEMMMMdyyyy" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[formatter setDateFormat:format];

NSString *dateFormatted = [fullDateFormatterTime stringFromDate: date];
NSLog(@"Formatted date: %@", dateFormatted);
```